# Widget factory extension of the jquery ui progress bar doesn't affect look of a div on a jsfiddle

Tags: jquery, jsfiddle, jquery-ui-widget-factory

I wanted to extend a progress bar using Widget Factory. When I tried sample script presented on JQuery site and copied it to jsfiddle it doesn't work. There are no errors.

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/tuoqes7h

HTML:

```
<div id="a">
bla
</div>
```

SCRIPT:

```
$.widget("custom.progressbar", {
  _create: function() {
    var progress = this.options.value + "%";
    this.element
      .addClass("progressbar")
      .text(progress);
  }
});


$(function() {
  $("#a").progressbar({
    value: 25
  });
});
```

Comment: You're not extending the progress bar, you're creating a brand new widget. You should pass `$.ui.progressbar` as the second argument to `$.widget()` in order to extend it. You will also have to chain to the base method in `_create()`.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Thank you for your comment. So what does the `addClass` function do?

Comment: It only adds a CSS class. Adding that class does not magically instantiate the widget.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi and I don't get any options/methods/events from progress bar just get's its styling?

Comment: Then it should be `ui-progressbar`, but even then I don't think you can reproduce the styling that way. The progress bar widget consists in multiple nested `<div>` elements, I'm afraid a single one won't do the trick. Your best bet may be to inspect the resulting markup and reproduce it.